# Is it possible to restrict printing to computers that are only logged in a domain

Tags: network-printer

I have three printers at my work station that are shared by their IP address, where any user either logged in a domain or not is allowed to print, but I wanted to restrict printing for users that are logged in the domain,

So any one who is not logged the domain is not allowed to make any kind of print.

Comment: Don't allow non domain machines to access the network?

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear on how these printers are setup.
You mention both "shared by their ip-address" and "at my workstation".

I presume you mean they are physically near to your workstation, but the printers are NOT shared to others VIA your workstation.
If that actually was the case you could simply set the permissions on the shared printer on your workstation to 'Domain users" or "Auhtenticated Users" only.
(Same applies if they are shared via a central print-server in your company, but in that case your system-admin is the one to talk too.)

So the printers are individually connected to the network and everybody connects directly to the printer they want to use.
In that case the printer itself must decide who is allowed to print. In most cases however there is no mechanism to do this.
The most common network print-protocols (JetDirect, LPR/LPD, IPP and Bonjour) are simply "open for everyone". (IPP has a way to have an printer ask for a password, but I have never seen an IPP printer that actually had that feature, or an IPP client that was able to supply the password.)

The only option I can see is that the printer itself can act as SMB print-share (which is basically the same as Windows Print-sharing) and allows the printing to be restricted to "Domain users" or "Authenticated" users.
Many business-grade printers have this ability but it does require some setup in the printer (e.g. the printer itself needs a valid user-account in the domain otherwise it can't ask the domain controller whether or not a user has permission to print) and you would need to disable all other printing-protocols as well (which, depending on business needs, may not be possible).